# How to align list items

Tags: html, css

I am giving a trial on how to style lists and using child selectors.
Currently I managed to style an unordered list as my jsfiddle displays:https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/mc5w2wqL/1/.

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul li:not(:first-child){
  color: red;
}
ul li:first-child{
  line-height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

At the moment the bullet disappeared, but the list did not move to the far left replacing the position of the bullet.
How can I align the first list item to the bullets of the other list items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your ul-items has an `padding-left: 40px;` If you set this to `0`, all items will go to left. If you want to change then the left-alignment of the li-items, you could use `margin-left` on them.

Just try and add this to your fiddle, and you will see that the first items move 20px to right, while all other items on the left.

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li:first-child {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

If you want to prevent the padding which accours then, just add `line-height: 100%;` to `ul li:first-child` like:

```
ul li:first-child {
  line-height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The ideally is almost there...just that you did it the other way around because the first list item is the one supposed to be on the place of the bullets where the other items will remain in the same position.
Check @Kevin Jantzer answer/jsfiddle above.
Appreciate the support

Answer (score 1):

Its because the `<ul>` has `padding` and `margin-before`.

> Add `margin-left:-1em` to align with bullets or `margin-left:-40px` to align with edge of page.

### https://jsfiddle.net/mc5w2wqL/3/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Indeed.Could not think that far bit. It works exactly as the jsfiddle. Voted